# Child Parent Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Copy data from Table1 to Table2. my code just work for the first time, the second time it does not send 0 in ParentId**

My scenario needs these points to fulfil:

1. parent-child hierarchy can go to n level.
2. A parent can have many children.
3. Table2 should not have Table1's Id and parentid data, but it must have its own ids and parentids but keep in mind parent-child relationship must match between both tables.

   ```
   -- Table 1
   create table #Table1 (
   Id int, ParentId int, Name varchar(50))
   insert into #Table1 values(6,0, 'person1')
   insert into #Table1 values(7,0, 'person2')
   insert into #Table1 values(8,7, 'person3')
   insert into #Table1 values(9,6, 'person4')
   SELECT * from #Table1

   -- Table 2
   create table #Table2 (
   Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ParentId int, Name varchar(50))

   -- below code copy table1 data into table2 on the first try, the second time it does not take correct data.
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Table2 ON
   declare @MaxId int;
   select @MaxId=max(id)from #table2; 

   ;WITH NewIDs AS (
     SELECT OriginalID=T.Id, ReplacementID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.ID ASC)
     FROM #Table1 AS T
   )
   INSERT INTO #Table2(Id, ParentId, Name)
     SELECT Id=N1.ReplacementID+coalesce(@MaxId, 0),
       ParentId=ISNULL(N2.ReplacementID, 0)+coalesce(@MaxId, 0),
       Name=T.Name
     FROM #Table1 AS T
     INNER JOIN NewIDs AS N1 ON T.Id=N1.OriginalID
     LEFT JOIN NewIDs AS N2 ON T.ParentId=N2.OriginalID

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Table2 OFF

   SELECT * from #Table1
   SELECT * from #Table2
   ```

**After two times execution I get this which is wrong (upper one is table 1, lower one table2) **

[image: it has 4 and 4 in parentId which is wrong, i want 0 and 0]

**The result i expect is**

[image: it has 0 and 0, this is what i want.]

Comment: @DaleBurrell Looks like SQL Server syntax to me.

Comment: SQL server @DaleBurrell

Comment: The error occurs because the first time you insert data, the data is not there. The second time you insert the same data, it is already there, so the primary key of table 2 prevents insertion of duplicate values

Comment: There is an attempt to create a replacement id, which I image is trying to solve the duplicate issue, but I think its getting row numbers from the wrong table.

Comment: I have added images, plz check them. @DaleBurrell  second image data is required. I am really stuck with this query.

Comment: this is what i want that second time when i insert data into table2. it should create its own Ids while taking care of parent child relationship. @CaiusJard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I'm not 100% sure this addresses your wider business logic case, but it does produce the results you expect. Basically when you come to create a replacement ID it has to start from the last existing ID in the table, so the following does that.

```
-- Table 1

create table #Table1 (Id int, ParentId int, Name varchar(50))
insert into #Table1 values(6,0, 'person1')
insert into #Table1 values(7,6, 'person2')
insert into #Table1 values(8,7, 'person3')
insert into #Table1 values(9,7, 'person4')
insert into #Table1 values(10,7, 'person5')
insert into #Table1 values(11,9, 'person6')
insert into #Table1 values(12,11, 'person7')
insert into #Table1 values(13,7, 'person8')

SELECT * from #Table1

-- Table 2
create table #Table2 (Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ParentId int, Name varchar(50))

-- below code copy table1 data into table2 on first
-- try, the second time it does not work.
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Table2 ON

declare @MaxId int; -- Change Line 1
select @MaxId = max(id) from #table2; -- Change Line 2

;WITH NewIDs AS
(
  SELECT
    OriginalID = T.Id
    , ReplacementID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.ID ASC)
    , ParentId
  FROM #Table1 AS T
)
INSERT INTO #Table2 (Id, ParentId, [Name])
  SELECT
    N1.ReplacementID + coalesce(@MaxId,0) -- Change Line 3
    , case when T.ParentId = 0 then 0 else ISNULL(N2.ReplacementID, 0) + coalesce(@MaxId,0) end -- Change Line 4
    , T.[Name]
  FROM #Table1 AS T
  INNER JOIN NewIDs AS N1 ON T.Id = N1.OriginalID
  LEFT JOIN NewIDs AS N2 ON T.ParentId = N2.OriginalID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Table2 OFF

SELECT * from #Table1
SELECT * from #Table2
```

Comment: Now the only issue is that ParentIds are not updated correctly on second execution.

Comment: Yeah thats where my understanding of what you are trying to accomplish falls down. But hopefully now that you can see what is wrong you have an idea of how to correct it? It might be as simple as changing  `ParentId = ISNULL(N2.ReplacementID, 0)` to `ParentId = ISNULL(N2.ReplacementID, 0) + coalesce(@MaxId,0)`

Comment: There is no row that equates to a parent id of 0 - maybe it should be 1? All the rest of your parent ids exist in the id column - 0 doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right, No id have 0, but my requirement is like this. the only parentid can have 0.

Comment: I don't understand - are you saying that ParentId 0 should stay 0 and not be changed?

Comment: Yes parent 0 will always remain 0 in parentId column.

Comment: @NaveedUllah I've fixed the parentId = 0 issue in my answer.

Comment: Sorry donot have access to machine, will give you response as soon as possible. thanks @Dale Burrell

Comment: 100% it is working now, once again Thank you so much. @Dale Burrell